# How can we detect People Name and his Designation/Role from a sentence using Deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, deep-learning, tensorflow

Let's say for a paragraph like:

`Satya Nadella is Chief Executive Officer of Microsoft. Before being named CEO in February 2014, Nadella held leadership roles in both enterprise and consumer businesses across the company. Another tech giant company is HP and Dion J. Weisler is President, Chief Executive Officer, Director of the Company. Previously, he served as Executive Vice President of the Printing and Personal Systems Group of Hewlett-Packard Company from June 2013 to November 2015.`

This will be as an input for deep learning model. And detected people and designation would be like:
[Satya Nadella, Chief Executive Officer]
[Dion J. Weisler, President]

Any idea how we solve this challenge and what should be the best deep learning algorithm for it?

Answer (score -1):

Read this state of art review paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02709.pdf

and this article:

https://medium.com/dair-ai/deep-learning-for-nlp-an-overview-of-recent-trends-d0d8f40a776d

Your problem generally falls into the "simple relation" types and this paper will be highly relevant:

http://acl2014.org/acl2014/P14-2/pdf/P14-2105.pdf

To be more concrete your solutions may involve several layers of functionalities:

a. First is to sift all the sentences that have simple vs non-simple relationship.

b. Next for the simple relationship you should again sift out (based on whitelisting all known vocations (eg, "CEO", "farmer", "singer" etc) and throw away all other sentences.

c. For what remains, you will want to extract out all "xxx is CEO" or "CEO is yyy" sentences.

d. Last step may be to eliminate sentences with common words as "xxx" or "yyy" above, for eg, "CEO is very happy", or "The dog belong to CEO".   A name is usually anything "not-seen-before".

Comment: Actually I implemented Named entity recognition system using deep learning. Which works for tagging person or the designation words. Here my question actually is it possible somehow get the person name with his designation using deep learning. Let say, we tag person name and designation name but we have to find a relation the person with his designation.

Comment: sounds exactly like this:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8sH8VM2Bd0&t=620s